# Power series with radius convergence $\leqslant 1$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Suppose that the coefficients of the power series $\sum a_nz^n$ are integers, infinitely many of which are distinct from zero. Prove that the radius of convergence is at most 1.

**Proof:** Let radius of convergence will be $>1$. Then $|a_nz^n|<1$ for $\forall n\geqslant N_1$. Hence $|a_nz^n|=|a_n||z|^n=|a_n|R^n<1$.

By condition exists increasing subzequence $\{n_k\}$ s.t. $n_1\geqslant N_1$ and $|a_{n_k}|\geqslant 1$. Hence $1<|a_{n_k}|R^{n_k}<1$. Contradiction.

Is my proof true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a_n $ are integers and $a_n \neq 0$ for infinitely many $n$ then $$\sqrt[n]{|a_n |}\geqslant \sqrt[n]{1}\geqslant 1  $$ for infinitely many $n$ and hence $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n |}\geqslant 1 .$$

Comment: Why $\limsup $ will be $\geqslant 1$?

Comment: Because there is a subsequence $(a_ {n_k} ) $ with all terms no less than $1.$

Answer (score 0):

I think the proof has the right idea, with some confusing wording. You do not explain what $R$ is, for example. You need to be careful about these things.

Comment: You are right! If the radius of convergence is $>1$. Then for any $z$ s.t. $|z|=R>1$ we got contradiction. Is that better?

Comment: @Pacman No, because if the radius of convergence is $R$, then the series does not need to converge for $z=R$. For exapmle, the series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$$ does **not** converge for $z=1$.

Comment: @ 5xum and how then to write?

Comment: @Pacman If $R>1$, then there exists some $z\in(1,R)$ for which you *can* be certain that the series converges.

Answer (score 0):

What can you say about $\sum a_n1^n$? What is this implying about the radius of convergence?